# Sending file via axios to laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, multipartform-data, quasar-framework

I am using [`Quasar` file picker](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/file-picker) to catching file from user to send into `Laravel` controller using `Axios`.When I send my data to `Laravel` controller, I receive an empty object. Please help me to solve this problem!

`Html` :

```
<q-file
   v-model="file"
   accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg"
   label="Select file"
/>
```

`Js` :

```
let config;
export default {
data() {
 return {
  file: null
},
methods: {
  send() {
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.file);

    Http.post('api/create', data, config)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response )
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      });
   }
},
created() {
  config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  };
}
```

result of `console.log(this.file,config);` is :

```
File {name: "WhatsApp Image 2020-12-07 at 10.25.00 PM (2).jpeg", lastModified: 1607540162000, lastModifiedDate: Wed Dec 09 2020 22:26:02 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 73419, …}
lastModified: 1607540162000
lastModifiedDate: Wed Dec 09 2020 22:26:02 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time) {}
name: "WhatsApp Image 2020-12-07 at 10.25.00 PM (2).jpeg"
size: 73419
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
headers:
Content-Type: "multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: everything is ok please in your controller dump(request()->all()); and add screenshot if you can

Comment: @anasomush In controller file: {}

Comment: @anasomush In header i have : file: (binary)

Comment: your issue in controller in frontend everything is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was about `laravel` controller that didn't show me received files in `return $request->all()` or `return $request()->files()` or `return $request->input('file)`.

I don't know it was about `api` or `laravel passport` but I save item in project dir and Done!

Answer (score 1):

You're super close. When working with file input fields you don't use the v-model as files are handled a little differently than normal data.

Instead listen for changes on the file input and then create the multipart form data and send to laravel.

Add a change event to your input that triggers your send method. The `$event` value will contain everything we need. ($event is a special variable for catching event data from fields).

```
<q-file
   accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg"
   label="Select file"
   @change="send($event)"
/>
```

Then slightly adjust your send method

```
export default {
  methods: {
    send(event) {
      // Don't go any further if no file was selected
      if (!event.target.files.length) return

      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('file', event.target.files[0]);

      Http.post('api/create', data, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response )
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error)
        });
    }
  }
}
```

Your uploaded file will then be available in Laravel via `$request->file('file');`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have other inputs and a button that send form to backend. How can I used it in my code ?

Comment: When i try to run : `console.log(event.target.files[0])` I have nothing :/

Comment: You can append the other data by adding more appends. eg:

`data.append('somethingelse', this.somethingElse);`